# haskell - will pattern matching work faster for non-specific form of an algebraic data type?

Tags: haskell, optimization, recursion, pattern-matching, algebraic-data-types

i have the following type:

```
data Tree a =   Empty |
                Branch {    key     :: a,
                            balance :: Int8,
                            left    :: Tree a,
                            right   :: Tree a,
                            up      :: Bool    --used internally to stop updating balance
                       }
                deriving (Eq)
```

and a function that matches the following pattern:

```
roll (Branch y (-2) l (Branch ry 1 (Branch rly 0 Empty Empty _) rr _) _) = ...
```

even though `Empty Empty` inside `(Branch rly 0 Empty Empty _)` is the only possible case, i was wondering - will generalizing the form to :

```
roll (Branch y 2 (Branch ly (-1) ll (Branch lry 0 lrl lrr _) _) r _) = ...
```

work faster (even negligibly) because runtime doesn't need to match `lrl` and `lrr` to `Empty` ?

Comment: Others have already said it "Yes, it might; benchmarking is only way to know". In more depth however it wouldn't have to evaluate those thunks to see if they were Empty which could potentially save a large computation which would speed things up a lot. That scenario seems unlikely but it will probably save a handful of cycles every time the pattern is matched which depending on the use case could add up to a lot

Answer (score 2):

It *might* yield a very tiny speed increase - you would have to benchmark it properly to know for sure. (If you're not going to look at `lrl` or `lrr`, you might as well use `_` instead.)

My personal recommendation would be to leave the explicit `Empty` patterns in there. You *say* "there is no other possibility", but having this documented in the code becomes very helpful in the unlikely event that you are in fact mistaken. ;-)

(It may also affect the overall strictness/laziness of your program - but that's an entire *other* discussion...)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be faster.  If its worth it, only benchmarking can tell.